# how to create one recycler view adapter for multiple viewholders that matches a viewholder of choice not in the same recycler view list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I would like to know how I can create ONE recycler view adapter that holds MULTIPLE view-holders and each time the RecyclerView is instantiated with that adapter,I want to see only a specific type rather than a mixed type.

I have 2 different screens in the Android activity and each of them shows a list of items/cards.One is of text and number and the other is a photo. Right now I have 2 different custom adapters for each object and what I want to achieve is the flexibility of one adapter that can defer between the types of objects according to the screen its displaying and list only the rows I need.

All the examples I've seen are of mixed type objects and it is not what I am after.

The Adapter code is appended below.

```
    public class MultiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<MYDataProvider> arrayList;
    private final static int VIEW0 = 0;
    private final static int VIEW1 = 1;

    public MultiAdapter(ArrayList<MyDataProvider> _arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.arrayList = _arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return VIEW0;

            case 1:
            default:
                return VIEW1;
        }//switch
    }//get item view type

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        int layoutRes;
        View view;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewholder;

        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW0:
                layoutRes = R.layout.card_item;
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(layoutRes, viewGroup, false);
                viewholder =  new E1(view);
                break;

            case VIEW1:
            default:
                layoutRes = R.layout.item_layout;
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(layoutRes, viewGroup, false);
                viewholder =  new E2(view);
                break;
        }//switch

        return viewholder;
    }//on create

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case VIEW0: {
                MyDataProvider mydata = arrayList.get(position);
                ((E1)holder).name1.setText(mydata.getD_name() + "this is item " + position);
                ((E1)holder).imageView1.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getImg_res());
            }
            break;

            case VIEW1: {
                MyDataProvider mydata = arrayList.get(position);
                ((E2)holder).name2.setText(mydata.getD_name() + "this is item " + position);
                ((E2)holder).imageView2.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getImg_res());
            }
            break;
        }//switch
    }//on bind


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    public class E1 extends mainViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView1;
        TextView name1;

        public E1(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            name1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.d_name);
        }
    }//e1 class

        public class E2 extends mainViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView2;
        TextView name2;

        public E2(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            name2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        }
    }//e2 class

    public class mainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public mainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}//adapter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get it where is your problem? Can you provide more explanation what you want to achieve?

// edit

In your code you determine that only first item will be item of type VIEW0 and others will be VIEW1. This is in `getItemViewType(int position)` function.

If you want determine what ViewHolder to pick you must to choose it before you populate list. Create enum in your adapter:

```
enum TYPE {
    VIEW0,
    VIEW1
}
```

then create variable of enum:

```
private TYPE itemType;
```

and pass it in your constructor:

```
public Test(ArrayList<MyDataProvider> _arrayList, TYPE itemType) {
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.arrayList = _arrayList;
    this.itemType = itemType;
}
```

and check what is your type (based on `itemType` variable) in your switch in `onCreateViewHolder` function like that. Note that variable in switch is "itemType", not viewType from override method.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
switch (itemType) {
    case VIEW0:
        return new NotificationsAdapter.ReferralTriggerViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_referral_trigger, parent, false));
    case VIEW1:
        return new NotificationsAdapter.UserNotificationViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_user_notification, parent, false));
    default:
        return new NotificationsAdapter.UserNotificationViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_user_notification, parent, false));
}

}
```

Comment: you can add this as a comment

Comment: I can't add comments, because I don't have 50 reputation :(

Comment: it would be easier to show a photo but i can't upload a photo here. my problem is that i have 2 objects, one for each list. the list that is being built takes both objects os it is like this:

wanted list1: A A A A A A A A
wanted list2: B B B B B B B B 

reality list: A B A B A B A B

Comment: I will describe it above  :)

Comment: @DennyDog thanks. ive already tried it. its all the same. i still get the mixed list. any other ideas?

Comment: Can you post your changed code with my idea? Maybe something is written wrong :)

Comment: @DennyDog hi, sorry for disappearing. i had other things to do and completely forgot about this. tomorow i will post the changed code with your suggestion so you will be able to see the result. just to mention that i thought about your idea before posting but it was all the same for me...

Comment: @EyalIsrael i added one more explanation to my answer :) Hope that will help!

Comment: @DennyDog. thank you for your help. i fixed my code to your suggestion but instead of enum i just used a primitive int variable and did everything else pretty much the same nad now i get exactly what i need. i am using the same one recyclerview list and one recyclerview adapter with different types of view holders.

Comment: @EyalIsrael I'm glad to help you :D

Answer (score 4):

```
public class NotificationsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_REFERRAL_TRIGGER = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION = 2;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION = 3;

    private List<Object> notificationObjectsList;
    private Activity mActivity;

    public NotificationsAdapter(Activity activity, List<Object> mNotificationList) {
        mActivity = activity;
        notificationObjectsList = new ArrayList<>(mNotificationList);
    }


    // Used to avoid the duplicate items recycling
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // Used to avoid the duplicate items recycling
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if ((notificationObjectsList.get(position) != null) && (notificationObjectsList.get(position) instanceof ReferralData)) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_REFERRAL_TRIGGER;
        } else if (notificationObjectsList.get(position) instanceof Promotion) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_REFERRAL_TRIGGER:
                return new NotificationsAdapter.ReferralTriggerViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_referral_trigger, parent, false));
            case VIEW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION:
                return new NotificationsAdapter.UserNotificationViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_user_notification, parent, false));
            case VIEW_TYPE_PROMOTION:
                return new NotificationsAdapter.PromotionViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_app_promotions, parent, false));
            default:
                return new NotificationsAdapter.UserNotificationViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout_user_notification, parent, false));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        if (viewHolder instanceof PromotionViewHolder) {
            final PromotionViewHolder promotionViewHolder = (PromotionViewHolder) viewHolder;
            //populate data of promotion view holder

        } else if (viewHolder instanceof UserNotificationViewHolder) {
            final UserNotificationViewHolder notificationViewHolder = (UserNotificationViewHolder) viewHolder;
            //populate data of UserNotificationViewHolder view holder

        } else if (viewHolder instanceof ReferralTriggerViewHolder) {
            final ReferralTriggerViewHolder referralTriggerViewHolder = (ReferralTriggerViewHolder) viewHolder;
            //populate data of ReferralTriggerViewHolder view holder
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notificationObjectsList.size();
    }


    private class UserNotificationViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private UserNotificationViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

        }


    }

    private class PromotionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {

        private PromotionViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }


    }

    private class ReferralTriggerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ReferralTriggerView referralTriggerView;

        private ReferralTriggerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            referralTriggerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rtv_notification_adapter);
        }
    }

}
```